# How to use a proxy with Google Web Toolkit

Tags: gwt, proxy

I am writing an application using GWT on Windows that needs to do some network calls.

I know that if these aren't to the same machine I'm developing on I need to setup a proxy, right?

I was just wondering if anyone could help with what my GWT code would look like?

What proxy should I use on Windows?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you're simply *requesting* data from a RESTful service from a different domain, you can use JSONP (http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tutorials/1.6/Xsite.html).

If you're trying to post data, you'd have to perform the network calls on the server side. (There are some hackish ways to try to submit via a hidden iframe, but they're non-standard). What this means is that you simply invoke a method on your server which does the network call (see http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tutorials/1.6/RPC.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean Google Web Toolkit, and you're trying to evade cross-domain scripting restrictions, check out Yahoo's [how-to guide](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html).  There's even PHP sample code.

Comment: That example actually involves writing your own PHP code as your own proxy.

What I am looking to do is simply have my application connect through a proxy to wherever it needs to get data.

Comment: So you want to use an open proxy?  That's not wise, as they come and go very frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Why not perform the network calls in server side? That way you are not restricted to cross domain restrictions.

Comment: I have tried
System.setProperty("socksProxyHost","hostname");
System.setProperty("sockProxyPort", "1234");
in a serverside class, and it gets ignored, at least when using the development mode browser plugins.  I get UnknownHostException that I shouldn't get when using the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=3131